# Count array of strings with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to count how many identical values there are in an array of strings using reduce but this.

```
const arrayOfStrings = ["63955a83c1a9a4d5365b686c", "63955e3e478e25a859a6e7bb", "63955e3e478e25a859a6e7bb"]

const result = arrayOfStrings.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  prev[curr] = prev[curr] || [{
    id: curr,
    amount: 0
  }];
  prev[curr][curr.amount] += 1
  return prev;
}, [])
```

I'm currently getting a strange array, but it's not even close to what I want, I'm expecting something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: "63955a83c1a9a4d5365b686c",
    amount: 1
  },
  {
    id: "63955e3e478e25a859a6e7bb",
    amount: 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Array indices are numeric, e.g., `foo[3]` gives you the 4th element. However, you're doing this: `foo["63955a83c1a9a4d5365b686c"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to initialise your `reduce` with an object rather than an array.
2. Update the `amount` by assigning the value to `acc[c].amount`.
3. Extract the values (the nested objects) with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
const arr = ["63955a83c1a9a4d5365b686c", "63955e3e478e25a859a6e7bb", "63955e3e478e25a859a6e7bb"];

const out = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  prev[curr] ??= { id: curr, amount: 0 };
  prev[curr].amount += 1;
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(out));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` inside reduce to search whether the value is already present in the array and if yes, then update the amount value, otherwise initialize a new object and push it in the array.

```js
const arrayOfStrings = ["63955a83c1a9a4d5365b686c", "63955e3e478e25a859a6e7bb", "63955e3e478e25a859a6e7bb"]

const result = arrayOfStrings.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  let o = prev.find((obj) => obj.id === curr)
  o ? o.amount++ : prev.push({ id: curr, amount: 1 })
  return prev;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```